# jQuery Attr Not Outputting

Tags: jquery, find

I'm trying to get jQuery's `attr` working on dynamic loaded content.

```
$('.content').find('.game-release').html($(this).attr("data-timer"));
```

`.content` is loaded in DOM, `.game-release` is loaded in AJAX dynamic content.

When I do this:

```
$('.content').find('.game-release').html("Hello");
```

The div changes to "Hello". When doing `$(this).attr("data-timer")` instead of "Hello", it doesn't do anything.

The div looks like this:

```
<div class="game-release" data-timer="10-08-2018 02:00:00">some text</div>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52805054/edit), then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a function for the HTML:

```js
$('.content').find('.game-release').html(function() {
  return $(this).data("timer")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="game-release" data-timer="10-08-2018 02:00:00">some text</div>
  <div class="game-release" data-timer="11-08-2018 02:00:00">some text</div>
  <div class="game-release" data-timer="12-08-2018 02:00:00">some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
$('.content').find('.game-release').html($(this).attr("data-timer"));
```

probably `this` is not the thing that you think it is. It is usually the object that the function was called on/from.

You would probably fix it using

```
var game_release = $('.game-release').first(); // Calling first because it's then more clear we're calling methods on only the first element in the collection, in case there are more .game-release elements.

game_release.html(game_release.attr("data-timer"));
```

You could try issuing a `console.log(this)` inside where you call the `.html()` to see for yourself what `this` is when you call the `.html()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var time = $(".game-release").data('timer');
$('.game-release').html(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="game-release" data-timer="10-08-2018 02:00:00">some text</div>
```